# How to fork & patch npm modules for angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, module, npm, fork

I have read this [fork and patch npm modules](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-fork-patch-npm-modules:4e2eb9f3-e584-44be-b1a9-3db7cbdd56cb) for set npm dependency to modules hosted in github, but it seems this doesn't work for angular2 type script module.

How to solve it, actually here is [my fork module](https://github.com/hoswey/ng2-smart-table)